Why, when this object is selected, does it not properly reflect its vertices in solid mode? (material preview looks fine)
I assume this is some silly error that I made along the way. I am new to blender and do not know why this is happening.



Some faces are inverted, each face has a direction that is represented by a normal, normals should point outwards of the object, here I've inverted a face of Suzanne, you can see that it is inverted in X-Ray mode, the face appears transparent:

In Object mode you can activate the Face Orientation option of the Viewport Overlays and the face will appear red:

In Edit mode you can activate the normals display in the Mesh Edit Mode Overlays:

To invert the normals, select the face and press AltN > Flip, or select all and recalculate the whole mesh normals automatically with ShiftN.

You're a saint. Thank you so much.
